# Finding the deleted files between two commits

Tags: bash, git, bitbucket, pull-request, git-diff

I'm currently writing a script in bash to find the deleted files between a pull request and the latest tag of the destination branch of the pull request. My idea is to get the commit id of both the pull request and the commit id of the tag and compare both of them to find the deleted files.

I'm using this command to find the diff between the commits

```
GIT_DIFF_RESULT=$(git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only "$commitid_of_latest_tag"..."$BITBUCKET_COMMIT")
```

My repository is in bitbucket and their variable `BITBUCKET_COMMIT` will give me the commit id of the pull request and `commitid_of_latest_tag` will me the commit of the latest tag in the branch.

I checked the execution and both the values from the variables are correct but the answer that I get is wrong. If I run it several times it will give me different answers for the same information.

Comment: That soinds like the valued of the commits is changing _per run_. Output changes with the same IDs if you run it on the terminal?

Comment: That what surprise me also the I use the same IDs

Comment: I think maybe the command I'm using is wrong, is there any way to resolve this

Comment: You are using the *three*-dot syntax (`A...B`), which does not compare commits `A` and `B`. You presumably want either the *two*-dot syntax (`A..B`) or the simpler (and recommended) form of `git diff A B`.

Comment: Note that if you want to look at *all* the commits in the `A..B`range, you must run multiple `git diff` or `git show` operations, one for each pair of commits that you wish compared. However, `A..B` or `A B` will show the final end result regardless of any intermediate steps (e.g., perhaps "between" A and B, someone deleted every file, then put them all back; the diff from A to B will ignore this).

Comment: Are you running this script in Bitbucket pipelines? When you say "if I run it several times it will give me different asnswers for the same information" what do you mean? How do you run it multiple times? Are you sure the input, including the state of the repositoyr, is exactly the same each time? Please show example runs to show the difference in the output.

Comment: My end goal is to run it using a pipeline in bitbucket, since that didn't work I started to test it locally using git with same commit hashes. That's when it starts giving me different answers for the same information.

Comment: So I started from the beginning and last time when I was adding files I didn't add any content to them but this time I did and that worked now it's working correctly.